# Square Root of Floats Error

Tags: python, math, floating-point, square-root

I created a very simple square root program and it would just immediately print the response for `elif b > x` when using floats. However, if I just used integers it works (but that means I can't find the square root of 9.61, for example).

Here is the program:

```
x = float(raw_input("What is the number?  "))
a = 1.0
b = a*a
while True:
    if b == x:
        print "The answer is", a
        break
    elif b > x:
        #print "a = ",a
        #print "x = ",x
        print "That is beyond my computing power. Sorry."
        break
    elif b < x:
        a = a + 0.1
        b = a*a
        continue
```

Comment: "would not work" is not a technical term. Please add more detail, e.g. expected vs. actual output, error messages etc.

Comment: In other words - what's the error you're getting?

Comment: Currently, this question is off-topic, as it's asking simply "why doesn't this code work", rather than giving enough details for the question to be useful to future users.  I'm not going to flag it, as it looks like you can edit it to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is checking for [**floating point equality**](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html).

The final iteration of your loop is comparing 3.1 * 3.1 against 9.61, and (the floating point representation of...) 3.1 * 3.1 is greater than 9.61, which terminates your loop with "beyond my computing power".

```
>>> 3.1 * 3.1 == 9.61
False

>>> 3.1 * 3.1 > 9.61
True

>>> 3.1 * 3.1
9.6100000000000001
```

If you want to compare floating point numbers like this, check that the difference between them is small enough ([**epsilon**](http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm)), instead of checking for equality.

If you want to explore more numeric methods for root finding, read the Wikipedia article on [**Newton-Raphson method**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method).

(Note: Some rational numbers can be represented by floats, so your loop might be able to find the square root of 3.61, for example.)